# YUI Rich Text Image Uploader Acting Inconsistently with Rails 3 Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, yui

I have a Rails app that uses YUI Rich Text Editor and Dennis AllMyBrain's YUI Image Uploader plugin from this post:
http://allmybrain.com/2007/10/16/an-image-upload-extension-for-yui-rich-text-editor/
and this repo:
https://github.com/mulicheng/yuiupload

I have the image uploader params set as follows:
yuiImgUploader(myBlogEditor, 'blogpost_content', '/blogpost_images','image');

The control seems to work on my new/create action, where I return an error because there's nothing to attach to:

> Started POST "/blogpost_images" for
>   127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-31 10:38:34 -0500   Processing by
>   BlogpostImagesController#create as
>   HTML

However, in the edit/update form, when I select an image, nothing happens in the broswer. In the console, I get a routing error:

> Started POST "/blogpost_images" for
>   127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-31 10:40:10 -0500
>
> ActionController::RoutingError (No
>   route matches "/blogpost_images"):

This is in development mode on my own machine, so I'm using WEBrick ATM. The two forms both include a partial, so they use the same form, and the same JavaScript. The submit URL's are slightly different, but the image upload URL appears to be exactly the same.

How can I track down what's different here?

Comment: It might be useful to include the relevant routes, as well as the HTTP request and response headers

Comment: I got this to work by changing "resources :blogpost_images" to "match :blogpost_images, :method => :post, :controller => :blogpost_images, :action => :create" in the routes.rb file. This made the create action route correctly in both cases. I'm not sure why this is the case, but I did this on another controller, and the sample Ruby script in the Image Uploader plugin also has this routing style.